# UGUI scripts stop my project from building

Tags: unity, android, build-process

Unity 2019.2.21

I am trying to build out my project to Android and I am getting the following error messages:

```
H:\unity versions\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\UI\Core\Toggle.cs(121,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'PrefabUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

H:\unity versions\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\UI\Core\DefaultControls.cs(152,13): error CS0103: The name 'Undo' does not exist in the current context

H:\unity versions\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\UI\Core\GraphicRebuildTracker.cs(24,32): error CS0117: 'CanvasRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'onRequestRebuild'

H:\unity versions\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\EventSystem\InputModules\StandaloneInputModule.cs(159,25): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EditorApplication' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

H:\unity versions\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\UI\Core\Slider.cs(380,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'PrefabUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

H:\unity versions\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\UI\Core\Scrollbar.cs(168,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'PrefabUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

H:\unity versions\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\UI\Core\Selectable.cs(771,48): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SceneManagement' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

H:\unity versions\2019.2.21f1\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.ugui\Runtime\UI\Core\InputField.cs(2458,43): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'PrefabUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

[image: screenshotoferror]

I tried updating Unity(from 2019.2.12 to current).
Deleting some csproj files, and different settings in the Project settings/Player.
The problematic code is in an #if UNITY_EDITOR statement, and not meant to execute at all on builds, I guess.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        protected override void OnValidate()
        {
            base.OnValidate();

            if (!UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.IsPartOfPrefabAsset(this) && !Application.isPlaying)
                CanvasUpdateRegistry.RegisterCanvasElementForLayoutRebuild(this);
        }

#endif // if UNITY_EDITOR
```

[image: problematiccode]

Comment: Looks like you're having an issue [similar to the one this user encountered](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/162157/39518) - but no answers there yet either. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the UGUI package through the package manager?

Comment: yes, just did, but no luck...should I report a bug?

Comment: Have you tried updating your package Manager?